# How does Break work in for-of loop when stopping a Generator?

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

So there are some ways to **stopping** a Generator in `for of` loop, but how does `break` send a signal to the Generator(in comparison with `return` in `for-of`)?

*please consider the code.*

As an example, the preceding code just increases a value from 1 to 10 ,and do **pause** and **resume** in between.

```
function *Generator() {

    try {
        var nextValue;

        while (true) {
            if (nextValue === undefined) {
                nextValue = 1;
            }
            else {
                nextValue++;
            }

            yield nextValue;
        }
    }
    // cleanup clause
    finally {
        console.log( "finally has been reached." );
    }
}
```

it loops over it 10 times by using `for of`:

```
var it = Generator();// it gets Generator's iterator

for (var v of it) {
    console.log(v); 

    if (v > 9) {

           //it.return("stop");//this is another tool for stopping, but it doesn't stop immediately.

           break; 

           console.log("it won't run");//this line won't run
    }
}
```

When `it.return()` is used by the way, the implementation's clear(`it` is the main Object and has got the control, but what about the `break`?);

Comment: You're breaking out of the for loop, what is it that you expect to happen with `break`?

Comment: shouldn't you just write "return;"  to exit the loop rather than "it.return("stop");", also you've used break inside the loop which should jump out the loop anyway.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking - but Break is used to break out of a loop (and continue any methods outside the loop). Return will break out of a method, not just a loop - and it can return a value. Break does not return a value.

Comment: Ok I'll add to question some more clearness.

Comment: Why do you name function `Generator`?

Comment: just because of clearness sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does `break` send a signal to the Generator?

The loop will call the [`IteratorClose` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-iteratorclose), which basically amounts to invoking the iterator's `.return()` method with no arguments if the iterator object has such a method - which generators do.
This also happens when a `throw` or `return` statement in the loop body is evaluated.

> When `it.return()` is used by the way, the implementation is clear

…but horrible. As you found out, it doesn't stop immediately. That's because a method call just advances the generator and gets you some result back from it, but is has nothing to do with your loop. The loop body will just continue to be executed until the loop condition is evaluated again, which then will check the iterator and notice that it's already done.

Answer (score 4):

Iterable objects like your `it` generator object have a property with the key `Symbol.iterator` that is a function returning an iterator. Iterators are required to have a `.next()` method to advance from one item to the next. Then can also optionally have a `.return()` method, which is called when you `break`, `return`, or `throw`, causing the `for..of` to stop before it runs to completion. So in your case, `break;` will automatically call `it.return()`.

The other side of it is that on ES6 generator, `.next()` makes it resume execution at the currently paused `yield`, and `.return()` makes it act like the `yield` is a `return` statement, so `break` inside the loop causes `yield nextValue;` to behave like `return;`, which will exit the generator and trigger the `finally` block.

Comment: I appreciate it, You said in my case `break` will automatically call `it.return()`, but it just put `{done: true}` which means we haven't actually break the `for-of` loop body, we just told our iterator that it's done.
So `break` after calling `it.return()` terminates its own loop iteration? (it does two jobs right?)

Comment: @MehdiRaash What do you mean by "*but it just put `{done: true}`*"? No, `break` breaks out of the loop like it always does, and then the `for` will call `it.return()` before continuing with the next statement after the loop.

Comment: Yeah, you never call `it.return()` yourself with `for..of`, just like you never call `it.next()` yourself. Putting a `break` in your loop will call `.return` for you.